# JQuery function not running

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write a function that is able to collect all the image URLs from a website as part of a larger application we are developing. We need the image URLs in order to display a product that we are recommending from a company website.

We are implementing our solution in the embedded HTML section of a shogun website and as a result, we decided to use JavaScript.

When I run the script in the browser developer tool (I am using Chrome), it is able to print out the URLs no problem however it does not run when I open the HTML file in the browser. Any recommendations on how I can fix this issue?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jscript.js">

var urls = []; 
const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
const url = 'https://somewebsite.com; 
$.get(proxyurl+url, function(data) {
    var imgs = $('<div>').html(data).find('img');
    imgs.each(function(i, img) {    
        urls.push(img.src); 
    });
    console.log(urls); 
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is that the exact code? You are missing opening script tags.

Comment: You're missing a closing quote on `const url = 'https://somewebsite.com; `

Comment: The example that you gave is pretty vague. Do you mind sharing some working code so that I or someone else can try to debug it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$.ajax` and handle error event to see error if having as

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data){ 
            var imgs = $('<div>').html(data).find('img');
            imgs.each(function(i, img) {    
            urls.push(img.src); 
            });
            console.log(urls); 
        },
        error: function(err) {
            alert('error!' + err);
        }
    });
```

Comment: This is not an answer. You could mention it to him in the comment section.

Comment: As j08691 pointed out, there's a typo. VTC this question as typo-based instead.